# Windows Phone WebBrowser Control

Tags: html, webbrowser-control, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to reference a local file from WebBrowser control? 
I have an image under Assets/Images folder of my project hierarchy. And i load the following html snippet.

```
<html><body>
    <img src='file:///Assets/Images/myimage.png' />
</body></html>
```

Is there a way to make this work?(Build Action of the image is **Content**)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kinda tricky but you can.

You have to use iso storage in order to display image in your html content
Check for this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333036/Include-static-JS-CSS-image-files-from-IsolatedSto

Comment: In WindowsPhone8 you don't need to copy files to isolated storage; the WBC now supports files directly from XAP - new WP8 feature